# Python: access to website without browser(without using selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

Currently, I am using Python and Selenium to access a website and then to input some data (about 20000 data) into the website.

Part of the code I have used:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('someTextFields').send_keys('XXXXXX')
browser.find_element_by_id('button').click()
```

However, using Selenium to do the job is very slow. I want a fast way to do this, to send keys and to click button. Can I access to the website without opening the browser?

Comment: You could try mechanise: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: as said above you can post using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). If you need to click and send keys with an alternative to Selenium have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser)